# Convert a perl regex to a python regex

Tags: python, regex, perl

I'm trying to convert a perl regex to python equivalent.

Line in perl:

```
($Cur) = $Line =~ m/\s*\<stat\>(.+)\<\/stat\>\s*$/i;
```

What I've attempted, but doesn't seem to work:

```
m = re.search('<stat>(.*?)</stat>/i', line)
cur = m.group(0)
```

Comment: Apart from anything else, you need to swap the arguments around: `re.search('<stat>(.*?)</stat>/i', line)`.

Comment: `+` means the same thing in Perl and Python, I'm not sure why you'd change `(.+)` to `(.*?)`.

Comment: Those two regex aren't equivalent.

Comment: @kylex Are there still problems not addressed by the answers?

Comment: @sweeneyrod, nope, I've marked an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

almost `/i` means case insensitive

```
m = re.search(r'<stat>(.*?)</stat>',line,re.IGNORECASE)
```

also use the `r` modifier on the string so you dont need to escape stuff like angle brackets.

but my guess is a better solution is to use an html/xml parser like beautifulsoup or other similar packages

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following ...

`r` is Python’s raw string notation for regex patterns and to avoid escaping, after the prefix comes your regular expression following your string data. `re.I` is used for case-insensitive matching.

See the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html) documentation explaining this in more detail.

To find your match, you could use the `group()` method of **MatchObject** like the following:

```
cur = re.search(r'<stat>([^<]*)</stat>', line).group(1)
```

Using `search()` matches only the first occurrence, use `findall()` to match all occurrences.

```
matches = re.findall(r'<stat>([^<]*)</stat>', line)
```